# openapi-generator only generates interfaces

Tags: openapi-generator

I am currently trying to gernate classes from my swagger.json file for my angular TS project. But OpenApi only generates interfaces. Is it possible to tell OpenApi generator to gernate classes instead?

Thank you for your help

Edit: I also found out that the variable `""type" : object"` in my swagger.json file is ignored by the OpenApi Generator